# iTextSharp PdfStamper add Header/Footer

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am trying to add a header or footer to pages within a pdf document. This is explained in the iTextInAction book as the correct way to add direct content to a page. However when I try to open this document in Adobe I get the following error, and have some issues printing as well. Any ideas?

[image]

```
Dim reader As PdfReader = Nothing
Dim stamper As PdfStamper = Nothing
Try
   reader = New PdfReader(inputFile)
   stamper = New PdfStamper(reader, New IO.FileStream(outputFile, IO.FileMode.Append))
Dim fontSz As Single = 10.0F
Dim font As New Font(font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, fontSz, 1, BaseColor.GRAY)
Dim chunk As New Chunk(headerText, font)
Dim rect As Rectangle = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)
```

Here I am just adjusting the size of the text to make sure it fits within the page boundaries

```
While chunk.GetWidthPoint() > rect.Width
  fontSz -= 1.0F
  font = New Font(font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, fontSz, 1, BaseColor.GRAY)
  chunk = New Chunk(wm.ToString(), font)
End While
```

This is where I get the overcontent and add my text to it

```
For pageNo As Int32 = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages
  Dim phrase As New Phrase(chunk)
  Dim x As Single = (rect.Width / 2) - (phrase.Chunks(0).GetWidthPoint() / 2)
  Dim y As Single = If(wm.WatermarkPosition = "Header", rect.Height - font.Size, 1.0F)
  Dim canvas As PdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(pageNo)
  canvas.BeginText()
  ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, x, y, 0)
  canvas.EndText()
Next
Catch ex As iTextSharp.text.pdf.BadPasswordException
  Throw New InvalidOperationException("Page extraction is not supported for this pdf document. It must be allowed in order to add a watermark.")
Finally
  reader.Close()
  stamper.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is probably this line:

```
stamper = New PdfStamper(reader, New IO.FileStream(outputFile, IO.FileMode.Append))
```

You are telling .Net to write the contents to a file in append mode. If the file doesn't exist then it creates the file but subsequent writes go to the end producing a corrupt PDF. You should change this to `IO.FileMode.Create`

Also, while you're at it, I usually recommend being even more explicit with your `FileStream` creation and tell .Net (and thus Windows) what you further intend for the stream. In this case, you are only ever going to write to it to you can say `FileAccess.Write` and while you are writing to it you want to make sure no one else attempts to read from it (since it would be in an invalid state) so you can say `FileShare.None`

```
stamper = New PdfStamper(reader, New FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
```

*(An aside, although using `IO.FileMode.Create` is absolutely valid it is really weird to see. Most people either spell it out as `System.IO.FileMode.Create` or they `import System.IO` and then just us `FileMode.Create`.)*